# How to use SimpleDateFormat to show the current Date?

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

i'm trying to get the current date and time formatted, this is my code:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmm");
String formattedDate=""+FORMATTER.format(date);
Log.d("XXxxxXxXXXXxxxXXXxXxxxX",formattedDate);
```

Something is going wrong because i'm getting this string: `19700103-0217`

That date is incorrect, I should get something like this: `20111118-1217`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Here is an example: [Android – Get Current Date and Time](http://www.technotalkative.com/?p=1689)

Comment: @Paresh Mayani, that's one way, but new Date() is another way that should work correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I can help you out but I have my own  code. Ask me if you don't get something.

First of all you have to make a class of any name like date.class and write  the code:

```
public class Date{
    private Date dt;
    private String stDt;
    private String enDt;

    SRSDDate(){
        dt=new Date();
        int mn;
        int yr;

        mn=dt.getMonth();
        yr=dt.getYear();
        mn=mn+1;
        yr=1900+yr;

        stDt="1/"+mn+"/"+yr;

        switch(yr%4){
            case 0:
                if(mn==2){
                    enDt="29/"+mn+"/"+yr;
                }
                else if(mn==1||mn==3||mn==5||mn==7||mn==8||mn==10||mn==12){
                    enDt="31/"+mn+"/"+yr;
                }
                else{
                    enDt="30/"+mn+"/"+yr;
                }
            break;
            default:
                if(mn==2){
                    enDt="28/"+mn+"/"+yr;
                }
                else if(mn==1||mn==3||mn==5||mn==7||mn==8||mn==10||mn==12){
                    enDt="31/"+mn+"/"+yr;
                }
                else{
                    enDt="30/"+mn+"/"+yr;
                }
            break;
        }
    }
    public String getTodayDate(){
        return (dt.getYear()+1900)+"-"+(dt.getMonth()+1)+"-"+dt.getDate();
    }
    public String getTodayDisplayDate(){
        return dt.getDate()+"/"+(dt.getMonth()+1)+"/"+(dt.getYear()+1900);
    }
    public String getStDt(){
        return stDt;
    }

    public String getEnDt(){
        return enDt;
    }
}
```

After making the class, you have to declare  this:

```
Calendar FromDateCal=Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener fd=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view,int year,int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
            FromDateCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            FromDateCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            FromDateCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateFromDate();
        }
};
```

Now find the edit box in which you want to display the date like:

```
Date dt=new Date();
FromDateText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.FromDateText);
FromDateText.setText(dt.getStDt());
```

Now you have to display date on edit box as follows:

```
private void updateFromDate(){
        int iDay;
        int iMonth;
        int iYear;

        iDay=FromDateCal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        iMonth=FromDateCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        iMonth=iMonth+1;
        iYear=FromDateCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        String sFDate=iDay+"/"+iMonth+"/"+iYear;
        FromDateText.setText(sFDate);
}
```

I hope you got my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your date is incorrect. It's hard to say how, as you haven't shown where it's coming from, but that's pretty much bound to be the problem. To confirm this, use the built-in `Date.toString()` method - that uses the system default time zone, so you need to be careful, but you should at least see the right date etc.

```
Log.d("date.toString() - ", date.toString());
```

Comment: Im creating date with this "Date date = new Date()", it must be initialized with the actual date as the documentation says. I edited my question with the full code

Comment: @AndroidUser99: Looks like the device/emulator doesn't have the correct date/time. Did you try the extra logging as I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the device (or emulator) on which you execute your code has an incorrect date. Your code should work as expected.

In any case, it's not related to `SimpleDateFormat`, ythe way you use it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to show current date then you can use `Calendar` though.

Using calendar,its pretty easy to get the date in desired format.

Ex:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
String year=String.format("%1$tY",cal);
String month=String.format("%1$tm",cal);
String day=String.format("%1$td",cal);

String hour=String.format("%1$tH",cal); // hour in 24 hour time format
String min=String.format("%1$M",cal);

String finalDateString=year+month+day+"-"+hour+min; //gives you in format like 20111118-1217
```

For more formates,refer [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Answer (score 1):

*To get Current Date. Try this*

```
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
```

//This will get you the current month.

Date date = calendar.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");

```
    String currentMonth = format.format(date);
```

//This will get you the current date of the month.

SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        String currentDate = format1.format(date);

If you need other formats, you can see this link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html