# How to automatically name taken screen shots by naming them by the date of their creation?

Tags: android, unix, date, filenames

My app takes a sequence of screenshots, but instead of getting lots of them, I get one screenshot that overwrites itself all the time. I want to get taken screenshots named by the date they were taken (it will make them unique and will solve the problem, i think).

For that I do the following:

```
$(date +%m.%d.%Y-%H:%M)
```

Full line:

```
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/fly/$(date +%m.%d.%Y-%H:%M).png").getBytes("ASCII"));
```

But the files don't appear.

I tried `/sdcard/fly/screenshot%d.png` but the files get named exactly like in the code "screenshot%d".

How can I properly name my files according to the date they were taken?

Full code:

```
package ru.startandroid.develop.p0921servicesimple;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
        someTask();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }

    void someTask() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "i = " + i);
                    try {
                        Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null);

                        OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
                        os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/fly/bob.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
                        os.flush();
                        os.close();
                        sh.waitFor();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: found right answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8182190/2177105. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Shell directives will not work when you do not run them in shell. It's just string for `exec`.
2. What about generating filenames in Java? There's for sure easy way of getting the same string as `date +%m.%d.%Y-%H:%M` writes out.